# Numpy slicing of a 3D matrix using a sequence `:n` is different than specifying columns `[0,1]`

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

Can anyone explain why the results below are different? In one case I specify `:2` which should be equivalent to `[0,1]`, but it is unexpectedly not.

```
x = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]])
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])

x.shape
(1, 3, 3)

# Works as expected
x[0, :, :2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])

# Not as expected, the results got transposed
x[0, :, [0,1]]
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8]])
```

Comment: It's the slice in the middle - it's a case of mixed basic and advanced indexing.

Comment: If you want to retain the shape in the last dimension, use `x[..., :2]`. If you mix and match advanced indexing and basic slicing, that's what you'll get..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53841497/901925

Comment: Here's a post which explains in detail: [why-using-an-array-as-an-index-changes-the-shape-of-a-multidimensional-ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829631/why-using-an-array-as-an-index-changes-the-shape-of-a-multidimensional-ndarray/55830708#55830708)

Comment: Thanks for the references, those do answer the question, I've voted this a duplicate now. Much appreciated.