# Problem simultaneously indexing several dimensions of a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider a 4-dimensional numpy array (variable a). We have a.shape = (16, 5, 66, 717).
From the second dimension containing 4 elements, I want to select the second and the fifth:

```
b = a[:, [1,4],:,:]
```

b.shape returns (16, 2, 66, 717), so I guess what I did is correct. Now I want to extract 4 elements from the first dimension (eighth, eleventh, twelfth, thirteenth) and two elements from the second dimension (second and fifth):

```
b = a[[7,10,12,13,14], [1,4],:,:]
```

which gives an error:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (2,)
```

I don't understand why this simultaneous indexing across >1 dimensions of numpy array doesn't work. I guess I could sequentially do b = a[:, [1,4],:,:] and c = b[[7,10,12,13,14],:,:,:] to get what I want, but there must be a way to do that in one step. Could you please help?

Comment: I guess you need `np.ix_`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325897/non-adjacent-slicing-of-numpy-multidimensional-array-in-python

Comment: when you use several indexing arrays, they `broadcast` against each other.  Here you want the first to be (5,1) shape,, which works with the (2,) to select a (5,2) block. `ix_` creates such a pair,

Comment: @hpaulj. How can I select all elements from a dimension with np.ix_? If I do  select = np.ix_([7,10,12,13,14], [1,4], :,:), the function returns an error.

Comment: The type of error is important!  `syntax error` means there's something wrong as the basic  python level.  It's raised by the interpreter before even calling `ix_`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a smaller 3d array:

```
In [155]: a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [158]: a
Out[158]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

Selecting two "rows" (on the middle dimension):

```
In [159]: a[:,[0,2],:]
Out[159]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

If we use 2 lists (or arrays) of the same shape, we end up selecting 2 "rows" from [159]:

```
In [160]: a[[0,1],[0,2],:]
Out[160]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

If instead the first list/array is a "column vector", we select a (2,2) "block":

```
In [161]: a[[[0],[1]],[0,2],:]
Out[161]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

`ix_` can be used to create the same 2 arrays:

```
In [162]: np.ix_([0,1],[0,2])
Out[162]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 2]]))
```

So using `ix_` arrays:

```
In [163]: I,J = np.ix_([0,1],[0,2])
In [164]: a[I,J,:]
Out[164]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

when I say they broadcast against each other, I mean in the same sense as broadcasting during adding or multiplication:

```
In [165]: I*10 + J
Out[165]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [10, 12]])
```

reference: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

### edit

```
In [166]: np.ix_([7,10,12,13,14], [1,4])
Out[166]: 
(array([[ 7],
        [10],
        [12],
        [13],
        [14]]),
 array([[1, 4]]))
```

Regarding your error:

```
In [167]: np.ix_([7,10,12,13,14], [1,4],:,:)
  Input In [167]
    np.ix_([7,10,12,13,14], [1,4],:,:)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`ix_` is a function.  ':' isn't allowed in a function call.  It only works in an indexing, where it's converted to a `slice`.  That's why you get a syntax error.

Comment: @ hpaulj Thanks for the clarification. I wonder if there is an easy way to select all elements (or say 100 elements) from my 4th dimension (that contains 717 elements). np.ix_ doesn't appear to allow that, unless you specify each index by end (which is a pain).

Comment: see my [164] example